# Vista Home Premium won't connect to network

Tags: networking, windows-vista, dhcp

I deinstalled some software (e.g. some Toolbars for IE and Norton security suite, because the free trial period of 60 days is run out and so i want to switch to microsofts free security essentials). But now i cannot connect to the network again:

- Neither over LAN nor over WiFi.
- Neither with standard DHCP ON (sets a 169.254.x.y address) nor with fixed IP-Address.

No error during changing the settings. Ping to the Gateway e.g. doesn't work and gives "generall failure". The DHCP-Client sets no IP-Address. There is allways only 'local access' on every network-connection.

i ran out of ideas, please help.

**UPDATE per 2011-03-11:**

I followed each and every hint but nothing changed. I did a research on microsofts homepage through all the sites belonging to network but nothing helped.

**What can i do next?**

**UPDATE per 2011-03-13:**

I did a system-repair, loosing all and everything stored on harddisk. This fixed the problem with network and thanks to the smart HP-Tool all the data was saved before, everything is fine: Norton has gone ms security essential is working and by the way i banned ie and choosed firefox.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: Good old norton security suite...when I worked at best buy this broke more systems than you could ever imagine when uninstalling the trial to put the full version on. Try this if you haven't already: http://us.norton.com/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20080710133834EN&ln=en_US

Comment: Sorry, this Norton - thing-a-magic is preinstalled on microsofts vista home premium as a 60 days offer - and once the 61. day is here - nowbody knows how to buy it nor wants to pay for something what was working for this periode of time without a noticeable use. And here it is me who has to help...

Comment: Norton Internet Security hacks so many portions of Windows that if anything goes wrong, it can cause all sorts of problems. The Norton Uninstall Tool is your best bet to put right all that Norton rearranged.

Comment: i did uninstall the norton suite with all the respect - and let the os reboot, but now nothing goes on network either LAN nor WiFi.
Security Essential is waiting for update, windows has reported some updates but no access. (It's not my first computer, i know who to check the network configuration and use some comandline tools).

Comment: The uninstall included with the app and the uninstall tool are very very different. If you just used what came with the application, it may not have uninstalled correctly.

Comment: i did the uninstall in windows software...(i didn't recognize a separate uninstall and know is nothing to see anymore in the menues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are getting an APIPA address (169.254...) when doing DHCP says your system either is not seeing the LAN (wire unplugged...) or else the TCP/IP stack is smashed.  If possible, download the LAN drivers from another computer and uninstall and reinstall the LAN devices on your system.  Hopefully that should recreate the stack.

Comment: That's a good idea but how to know which *.dll and all that stuff has to be uninstalled and where to download it for new?

Comment: Did a RESET according the following hint: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/06/19/reinstall-and-reset-tcpip-internet-protocol-in-windows-vista-2003-and-xp/

Nothing better, even a ping on the fix set IP gets a general failure! WHat the hell is going on?

Comment: Following your hint, i should deinstall the device in Device-Manager e.g. the WiFi and windows vista will detect the device on reboot again an re-install the drivers, right?

Comment: That or you can try and find the newest, most up-to-date driver (check both your computer manufacturer's website and also the device manufacturer's website) and simply download it.  Uninstall the current device from Device Manager and then install the new driver.

Answer (score 0):

As a (near) last resort, try resetting IE to defaults (Tools>Internet Options, then click the "Advanced" tab and look near bottom for "Reset" button). PS: MS Security Essentials is great, give it a try.

Comment: I did it, but no change: network-connection 'only local' that means even with a fix IP-configuration no access to anything, i'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

In order to close this thread and accept an answer i but my last update here explicit as answer.

UPDATE per 2011-03-13:

I did a system-repair, loosing all and everything stored on harddisk. This fixed the problem with network and thanks to the smart HP-Tool all the data was saved before, everything is fine: Norton has gone ms security essential is working and by the way i banned ie and choosed firefox.

Thanks to all who tried to help.